# How to find bright areas inside an image (and also how to find shaded areas in an image)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have an image:

[image: 1]]

How do I find areas of different intensity in an image? How do I find all the bright areas that differ to the original brightness, and contrary-wise, how to find the dark areas, originating from shadows in this case?

Human eye realises the change in brightness, but how would a program do that?

Comment: When you say brightness, do you mean a set value?

Comment: For starters it would probably be okay for me to say something like: if red is in range(240, 255) and blue is in range(240, 255) and green is in range(240, 255), that pixel is bright, but I am searching for smarter ways than that to look at each pixel, if there are any.

Comment: Do you want a histogram? https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html

Comment: Just wondering (since I'm new to this topic), could you take a group of pixels, and find the average of that?

Comment: @Zlatomir This is interesting, but how would I plot that on an image like: "Okay these areas are really bright, draw me a red rectangle in those regions", or: "These areas are pretty dark, draw me a circle in those areas", only for pretty dark and pretty bright parts, if you understand what I mean?

Comment: @FuzzySquid that is an interesting approach, tbh. :) EDIT: I have no clue how to access each individual pixel for that, though, hahaha :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find bright and dark spots in one picture:** 
There are multiple approaches to this. I am gonna suggest just a couple of them here.

1. You can find the mean of the RGB values of the image and use the lower 10% of the pixels which vary the most from the mean as darker pixels and the highest 10% of the pixels which vary the most from the mean as brighter pixels.
2. You can set a predefined threshold for a bright pixel, lets say RGB=[220,220,220] and dark pixel as RGB=[30,30,30] and iterate through the image and classify the pixels accordingly.

You can also look into dynamic thresholding for the second method and your approach to the problem can be optimised accordingly.

**Find changes in bright and dark spots:**
There are multiple ways to handle this as well. One approach can be the mean-value subtraction technique. The human eye responds to change with respect to the previous image which was perceived. The program needs to do the same where it needs to compare the changes to the previously captured frame(s). Look into temporal filtering to get a further  idea about this..

Hope this helped